# Configure DIH in multicore solr

Tags: solr, dih

I have a multicore implementation of solr. I want to configure DIH / core. I manage to make it work on single core solr. What I assume, I have to make the configurations / core, which means I create the data-import.xml in the core's conf directory and rewrite solrconfig.xml of the core. I also copied in the lib the maching driver for dih, but I get an error message:

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class
>   'org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler'    at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:389)
>   .............................................
>
> Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)     at
>   java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:615)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:373)
>     ... 49 more

Any clue, what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dataimporthandler isn't included anymore in the solr.war. You should add the jar `apache-solr-dataimporthandler-x.x.x.jar` (please replace the x.x.x with your current version) to your classpath. You can find it in the dist folder of the solr zip file you've downloaded.