# How to fix SolrException: Error loading class 'dataimport.DataImportHandler'?

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I just follow this [DIHQuickStart](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHQuickStart)， try to import data to solr from mysql.

Add request handler into solrconfig.xml

```
....

<!-- A request handler for demonstrating the elevator component -->
  <requestHandler name="/elevate" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <str name="df">text</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>elevator</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- Add by me-->
  <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

My data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
              driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" 
              user="root" 
              password="Pwd2011"/>
  <document>
    <entity name="subject" 
            query="select id,name,description from subject">
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Add drop mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar into lib folder.

Now I start tomcat（which is my solr servlet container). Access localhost:8180/solr,
Now I got error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Severe errors in solr configuration. Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong. If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change: <abortOnConfigurationError>false</abortOnConfigurationError> in solr.xml ------------------------------------------------------------- org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler' at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:394) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:419) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:455) at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:159) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:563) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:483) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:335) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:219) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:161) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:96) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4624) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5281) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:866) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:842) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1581) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423) at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:789) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:378) ... 27 more
```

I have checked all the folders of solr and tomcat, there is no further more log.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225650/configure-dih-in-multicore-solr May be this post will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your class path , looks like DataImportHandler is not on your classpath

Comment: Where are the import handlers supposed to be placed ? In the solr home directory right ? For one I cannot determine where the handlers are actually available in my solr download .