# Solr 4.5 with Tomcat 8 DataImportHandler with MSSQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, tomcat, solr, dih

I have tried all the other questions and some tutorials in the internet. All ends in the same error. CLass Not Found Exception.
Ich have installaed solr under `C:\solr` the home directory is `C:\solr_home` and the installation of Tomcat is under `C:\Tomcat`
I have copied the Microsoft Driver in the `C:\Tomcat\lib` folder

C:\solr_home\collection1\conf\solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

...

```
<lib dir="C:/solr/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
```

C:\solr_home\collection1\conf\data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource 
        driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://PC0815\DBPC0815;databaseName=Sampledocs" 
        user="XXXX"
        password="XXXX" 
    />

    <document>
        <entity name="Docs" query="SELECT FieldId, FieldTitle, FieldContent from Docs">
        <field column="FieldId" name="id" />
        <field column="FieldTitle" name="title" />
        <field column="FieldContent" name="description" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I get the following errors

```
    HTTP Status 500 - {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: 
    org/apache/solr/util/plugin/SolrCoreAware,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: 
    SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: 
    org/apache/solr/util/plugin/SolrCoreAware at 
    org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:785) at 
    org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:295) at
     org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:195) at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.ja
    va:241) at 
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:223) at 
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:107) at 
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) at 
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:75) at 
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:934) at 
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:90) at 
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:494) at 
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
     at 
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:
    632) at 
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtoco
    l.java:223) at 
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1592) at 
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1550) at 
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at 
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at 
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: 
    org/apache/solr/util/plugin/SolrCoreAware at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>
    (SolrCore.java:834) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:625) at 
    org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:524) at 
    org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:559) at 
    org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:249) at 
    org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:241) at 
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) at 
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at 
    java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) at 
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) at 
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ... 3 more Caused by: 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/util/plugin/SolrCoreAware at 
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at 
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at 
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at 
    java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at 
    java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown
     Source) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at 
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at 
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown 
    Source) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown 
    Source) at 
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1452) at 
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at 
    java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at 
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at 
    java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at 
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) at 
    org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:433) at 
    org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:381) at 
    org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:526) at 
    org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:599) at 
    org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:153) at 
    org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:768) ... 13 more Caused by: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.util.plugin.SolrCoreAware at 
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown 
    Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at 
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown
     Source) ... 40 more ,code=500}
```

Comment: Ok i have solved the problem. But i think it is a bad way?! I have copied all the lib files from .......\solr-4.5.0\contrib\extraction\lib to the `C:\Tomcat\webapps\solr\WEB-INF\lib` folder and it works fine. But i think the jar files should be loaded by Tomcat automaticly?! Is that a problem of the sorlconfig.xml configuration? (`<lib dir="C:/solr/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />`)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that DIH is a contrib module, which means that implicitly is not included. I see you manage to solve your problem. Please take a look at that:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225650/configure-dih-in-multicore-solr)